# Angular Java Jenkins build fail on angular upgrade from 6 to 8

Tags: angular, jenkins, build, upgrade

I am using angular 8 and node version 10 with back end as JAVA 8. When I try to make a build on my Jenkins server it gives me following error in console output . Recently I upgraded to angular 8 from 6 , build was running perfectly till the time i was running angular 6 and node 8 version .

[image]

I have tried every possible solution on internet like reinstalling npm , node etc. but nothing worked.
  This is my pom.xml file used for Jenkins configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>uk.co.apexx</groupId>
    <artifactId>apw</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>apw</name>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshot Releases</name>
            <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
        <servlet-version>3.1.0</servlet-version>
        <jsp-version>2.3.1</jsp-version>
        <commons.lang-version>2.6</commons.lang-version>
        <org-junit-version>4.12</org-junit-version>
        <org.apache.httpcomponents-version>4.5</org.apache.httpcomponents-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <org.log4j-version>1.2.15</org.log4j-version>
        <mysql-connector-java-version>5.1.46</mysql-connector-java-version>
        <org.hibernate-version>5.3.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
        <org.flywaydb-version>5.1.4</org.flywaydb-version>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <commons-dbcp2-version>2.3.0</commons-dbcp2-version>
        <jackson.databind-version>2.9.6</jackson.databind-version>
        <io.springfox-version>2.9.2</io.springfox-version>
        <io.swagger-annotation-version>2.0.3</io.swagger-annotation-version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
        <javax.annoation.version>1.3.2</javax.annoation.version>
        <project></project>
        <path></path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons Lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- org.jUnit Testing - Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${org-junit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons Http Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.httpcomponents-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql-connector-java-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Flyway Db -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.flywaydb-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring-Security-Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp2-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${io.springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger-annotation-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.annoation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>third-party</id>
            <name>third party</name>
            <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>Local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                            <warName>apw</warName>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java-version}</source>
                            <target>${java-version}</target>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.6</version>

                        <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.16.2</nodeVersion>
                            <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm-install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>dist/apexx-portal-ui</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
                <finalName>apw</finalName>

            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Apexx</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                            <warName>apw</warName>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java-version}</source>
                            <target>${java-version}</target>
                            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target name="copyresources">
                                        <copy todir="src/main/resources/" overwrite="true">
                                            <fileset dir="${project}" />
                                        </copy>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <append>true</append>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>

                            <execution>
                                <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent-for-it</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.6</version>
                        <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v8.11.4</nodeVersion>
                            <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                            </executions>
                        </configuration>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm-install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>dist/apexx-portal-ui</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
                <finalName>apw</finalName>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>


Any help will be highly appreciated.
```

Comment: you  will have to rollback the versions of  following: node.js ,  angular cli , npm (both in local and package.json)

Comment: in case of package.json you can go for git history and check what version you had before the upgrade

Comment: I know earlier version what I was using.. But currently my requirement is to upgrade to version 8 with successful build on Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

After trying for few days .. I successfully achieved upgradation from angular 6 to 8 and successfully build on Jenkins Server.
    For same I did few steps :

1. I commented  all steps related to node and npm install from pom.xml , so now my pom.xml looks like this.

   ```
      <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>uk.co.apexx</groupId>
       <artifactId>apw</artifactId>
       <version>${revision}</version>
       <packaging>war</packaging>

       <name>apw</name>
       <distributionManagement>
           <repository>
               <id>releases</id>
               <name>Internal Releases</name>
               <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
           </repository>
           <snapshotRepository>
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>Internal Snapshot Releases</name>
               <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
           </snapshotRepository>
       </distributionManagement>

       <properties>
           <spring.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</spring.version>
           <java-version>1.8</java-version>
           <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
           <servlet-version>3.1.0</servlet-version>
           <jsp-version>2.3.1</jsp-version>
           <commons.lang-version>2.6</commons.lang-version>
           <org-junit-version>4.12</org-junit-version>
           <org.apache.httpcomponents-version>4.5</org.apache.httpcomponents-version>
           <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
           <org.log4j-version>1.2.15</org.log4j-version>
           <mysql-connector-java-version>5.1.46</mysql-connector-java-version>
           <org.hibernate-version>5.3.0.Final</org.hibernate-version>
           <org.flywaydb-version>5.1.4</org.flywaydb-version>
           <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
           <commons-dbcp2-version>2.3.0</commons-dbcp2-version>
           <jackson.databind-version>2.6.3</jackson.databind-version>
           <io.springfox-version>2.9.2</io.springfox-version>
           <io.swagger-annotation-version>2.0.3</io.swagger-annotation-version>
           <log4j.version>1.2.15</log4j.version>
           <javax.annoation.version>1.3.2</javax.annoation.version>
           <project></project>
           <path></path>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       </properties>

       <dependencies>
           <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <scope>compile</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Logging -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
               <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
               <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
               <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>log4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
               <version>${log4j.version}</version>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                       <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                       <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
           </dependency>

           <!-- JSTL -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
               <version>${jstl-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Servlet -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
               <version>${servlet-version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
               <version>${jsp-version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Commons Lang -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
               <version>${commons.lang-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <!-- org.jUnit Testing - Start -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
               <version>${org-junit-version}</version>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
           <!-- Commons Http Client -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
               <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
               <version>${org.apache.httpcomponents-version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <!-- MySQL Connector -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>mysql</groupId>
               <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
               <version>${mysql-connector-java-version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <!-- Flyway Db -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
               <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
               <version>${org.flywaydb-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Spring-Security-Core -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
               <version>${commons-dbcp2-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Jackson Mapper -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
               <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
               <version>${org.hibernate-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <!-- Dependency for Swagger -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
               <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
               <version>${io.springfox-version}</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
               <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>${io.swagger-annotation-version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
               <version>${javax.annoation.version}</version>
           </dependency>

       </dependencies>
       <repositories>
           <repository>
               <id>releases</id>
               <name>Releases</name>
               <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
           </repository>
           <repository>
               <id>third-party</id>
               <name>third party</name>
               <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
           </repository>
           <repository>
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>Snapshots</name>
               <url>http://192.168.49.14:8585/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
           </repository>
           <repository>
               <id>maven-restlet</id>
               <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
               <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
           </repository>
       </repositories>

       <profiles>

           <profile>
               <id>Local</id>
               <activation>
                   <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
               </activation>
               <build>
                   <resources>
                       <resource>
                           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                       </resource>
                   </resources>
                   <plugins>
                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.4</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                               <warName>apw</warName>
                               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>

                       </plugin>

                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.3.2</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <source>${java-version}</source>
                               <target>${java-version}</target>
                               <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                               <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                               <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                           <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.7.6</version>

                           <dependencies>
                       <dependency>
                           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                           <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                           <version>4.4.4</version>
                       </dependency>
                       <dependency>
                           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                           <version>1.2</version>
                       </dependency>
                   </dependencies>
                           <!--<configuration>
                               <nodeVersion>v8.11.4</nodeVersion>
                               <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>

                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>install-npm</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>npm-install</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>npm-build</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>-->
                       </plugin>

                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
                                       <resources>
                                           <resource>
                                               <directory>dist/apexx-portal-ui</directory>
                                           </resource>
                                       </resources>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>

                   </plugins>
                   <finalName>apw</finalName>

               </build>
           </profile>
           <profile>
               <id>Apexx</id>
               <activation>
                   <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
               </activation>
               <build>
                   <resources>
                       <resource>
                           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                       </resource>
                   </resources>
                   <plugins>

                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.4</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                               <warName>apw</warName>
                               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>

                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.3.2</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <source>${java-version}</source>
                               <target>${java-version}</target>
                               <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                               <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                               <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.8</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                                   <phase>compile</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>run</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <target name="copyresources">
                                           <copy todir="src/main/resources/" overwrite="true">
                                               <fileset dir="${project}" />
                                           </copy>
                                       </target>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.8.2</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                           <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                               <append>true</append>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>

                               <execution>
                                   <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>agent-for-it</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>jacoco-site</id>
                                   <phase>verify</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>report</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>

                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                           <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>1.7.6</version>
                           <!--<configuration>
                               <nodeVersion>v8.11.4</nodeVersion>
                               <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                               <executions>
                                   <execution>prepare-package</execution>
                               </executions>
                           </configuration>

                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>install-npm</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>npm-install</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>npm-build</id>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>npm</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>-->
                       </plugin>

                       <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <id>copy-resources</id>
                                   <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                   </goals>
                                   <configuration>
                                       <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
                                       <resources>
                                           <resource>
                                               <directory>dist/apexx-portal-ui</directory>
                                           </resource>
                                       </resources>
                                   </configuration>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>

                   </plugins>
                   <finalName>apw</finalName>
               </build>
           </profile>
       </profiles>
   </project>
   ```
2. Now main problem was that due to linux OS on my Jenkins server, there were permission problem for few of my node_modules folders , so build was getting failure every time.
   So In my script section for Jenkins , I changed all directories permission for Jenkins workspace like

> chmod 777 "Jenkins_nodeModules_path"

3. then I added

> "sudo npm install"

to same script.

So these changes were made on Jenkins project configuration to build project successfully.Hope it helps someone :-)